# Iphone-MultiButton-Events

Tags: iphone

I Have One Xib File
IN Which There Are About 50 Buttons..

And All Are Have Same Functionality...
Like
On Click I Change Background Image (Select)And...
And Second Time Click Also Change Background Packet (Deselect)
..

If I Make All Button Own Events .. Then It's Ok..

But I Want To Create Single Function Which Handles All Buttons...

I Try It.. I Can't Get Specific Typecasting

Coding

.h File

```
-(IBAction) BtnShpPress:(id)sender;
```

.m File

```
-(IBAction) BtnShpPress:(id)sender
{
    UIButton *BtnShp= (UIButton * ) sender;
    NSString *Str = BtnShp.name; //Here I Ca't Get Specific Object
}
```

And I Apply This Event On 4 Buttons - TouchDown Events

Answer (score 0):

use this to get title -

```
NSString *Str = [[BtnShp titleLabel] text];
```

Comment: Wrong—that returns the `UILabel` that _displays_ the title. The correct method would be `[BtnShp currentTitle]`.

Answer (score 0):

```
-(IBAction) BtnShpPress:(id)sender
{
    UIButton *BtnShp= (UIButton * ) sender;
    NSString *Str = [BtnShp currentTitle]; //This gives title of button
}
```

You can also set tag and access them too using `button.tag`